# VBA: Function marked as restricted using dll

Tags: c#, excel, vba, dll

I wrote a C# dll that uses TCP sockets to send information from the client to the server. I am using the StartClient function from my dll but running into the error: Function marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic.

The error occurs at the returnValue= sabatheWise.StartClient(port, IpAddress, buffer) line with StartClient highlighted in yellow. I think the error is occurring due to one of the parameters I have identified. Also, even though I declare port as an int in my dll, when I look at Object browser in VBA, I see port as identified as long. It doesn't make a difference in my VBA code if I put port as long or as an integer, I receive the same error.

Any guidance on this will be appreciated.

Here is the VBA code:

```
Sub TestProgram()

Dim port As Long
port = 15050
Dim IpAddress As String
IpAddress = "192.123.456.78"
Dim buffer() As Byte
'Dim BufferSize As Integer
'BufferSize = 16048
Dim sabatheWise As TCPMessage.AsynchronousClient
Set sabatheWise = New TCPMessage.AsynchronousClient
Dim returnValue As Long
returnValue = sabatheWise.StartClient(port, IpAddress, buffer)
If returnValue = 0 Then Debug.Print "The program was successful"
If returnValue = -1 Then Debug.Print "The program failed"

End Sub
```

Here is the relevant portion of the dll:

```
 public int StartClient(int port, string IpAddress, byte[] buffer)
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.         
        try
        {

            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            client.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
```

Comment: Are you ever filling the `buffer`? Everything else *looks* fine, but it's the only thing I can quickly spot with your calls.

Answer (score 1):

The method is marked as restricted because `byte[] buffer` is not supported. To make it work, define the buffer to be marshalled by reference and make sure that the buffer is assigned:

```c#
public int StartClient(int port, string IpAddress, ref byte[] buffer) {
    ...
}
```

```vb
Dim buffer(0 to 16048) As Byte
Dim client As New TCPMessage.AsynchronousClient
Dim returnValue As Long

returnValue = client.StartClient(3838, "127.0.0.1", buffer)
```